# Regex for 9 Char in which 8 must be number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on JavaScript and have very basic requirement. 
Need pattern to see 9 length in string, in which 8 must be number from starting and last must be char be present.

**Examples:**

Valid values:

> 12345678 
>   
>   12345678a

Invalid values:

> a12345678 
>   
>   12345678aa

For that I wrote the following pattern:

```
var externalId = value;
var matchArr = externalId.match(/\d{0,8}[a-z|A-Z]?)/);
console.log(matchArr);
```

But it's not working as expected.
Could some one help me on this?

Comment: How is `12345678` valid when it doesn't have the last character?

Comment: If you want exactly 8 numbers followed by an alphabetical character, use this : `/^\d{8}[a-zA-Z]$)/`

Comment: Does `123a45678` is valid?

Comment: It looks like live input validation. If not, just use `/^\d{8}[a-zA-Z]?$/` - 8 digits and an optional alpha char (matched as a whole string).

Comment: `\d{0,8}` means "zero to 8 digits" not "strictly eight digits"

Comment: @Seblor You just added `|` as valid last character

Comment: [`\b\d{8}[a-zA-Z]\b`](https://regex101.com/r/S967xo/1/)

Comment: @Justinas oh yes thanks my bad. I edited my comment.

Comment: Should `12345678` of `12345678 12345678a` also be captured ?

Comment: also on top of what have been said so far there is an extra closing parenthesis `)` in your regex without equivalent opening `(` parenthesis!!!

Answer (score 1):

To match 8 numbers followed by letter use pattern `/^\d{8}[a-z]?$/i`

```js
function check(el) {
var externalId = $(el).val();
var matchArr = externalId.match(/^\d{8}[a-z]?/i);
console.log(matchArr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter 8 numbers and letter: <input type="text" id="text" onChange="check(this)"/>
```

---

Problem with your regex (`/\d{0,8}[a-z|A-Z]?)/`):

`\d{0,8}` - allows from 0 to 8 numbers sequence.
`[a-z|A-Z]` - allows uppercase, lowercase letters **and "|"** - it's not groups separator, it's literal "|".
`[...]?` - allows zero or one character from previous group.
`)` - is literal ")" and not capturing group end, because no start of group found

Comment: The last character (letter) might be optional `/^\d{8}[a-z]?$/i` as mentioned in the `valid values` of the OP question... anyway, it is kind of unclear what he wants! Nice answer, +1!

Answer (score 0):

This Regex captures every String with 8 numbers and one char.

```
(\d{8}[A-z])(?:$|\s)
```

Answer (score 0):

this regex capture 8 number and one letter max.

```
^[\d]{8}[A-z]{0,1}$
```